# Get the type of the generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following classes

```
public interface InterfaceBase
{
}

public class ImplementA:InterfaceBase
{
}

public class ImplementB:InterfaceBase
{
}

public void TestImplementType<T>(T obj) where T: InterfaceBase
{
}
```

How to infer what the T is whether ImplementA or ImplementB? I tried to use

```
typeof(T) is ImplementA
```

but this expression is always evaluated to false.

Edit: And how am I going to cast obj to ImplementA or ImplementB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`obj is ImplementA`

Comment: Again, that doesn't say that T derives from ImplementA - it only talks about the particular value of obj. TestImplementType<InterfaceBase>(new ImplementA()) will pass when (according to the actual question) it shouldn't.

Answer (score 9):

Strictly, you should avoid too much specialization within generics. It would be cleaner to put any specialized logic in a member on the interface, so that any implementation can do it differently. However, there are a number of ways:

You can test "obj" (assuming it is non-null)

```
    bool testObj = obj is ImplementA;
```

You can test T for being typeof(ImplementA):

```
    bool testEq = typeof(T) == typeof(ImplementA);
```

Likewise you can test it for being ImplementA or a subclass:

```
    bool testAssign = typeof(ImplementA).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T));
```

Answer (score 4):

`typeof(T)` returns the `Type` of `T` - and `System.Type` doesn't implement `ImplementA`. What you want is:

```
if (typeof(ImplementA).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
 if(obj.GetType().Equals(typeof(ImplementA)))
 {
   // ...
 }
```

Comment: That's not the same thing. For instance, you could call:

TetstImplementType<object>(new ImplementA())

Comment: Actually, the compiler won't let you instantiate TestImplementType<object>.

The type System.Object does not implement InterfaceBase.

Comment: Oops, hadn't seen the constraint. However, the root point is sound - typeof(T) isn't the same as obj.GetType(). You could certainly write TestImplementType<InterfaceBase>(new ImplementA()). Furthermore, this example doesn't cope with classes derived from ImplementA.